# Алгоритм сортировки массива

Tags: алгоритм

Дан массив из n элементов, нужно упорядочить в массиве эти элементы так, чтобы сначала шли четные, а потом нечетные.

Comment: Подходит?
http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread218110.html

Comment: @cheremushkin, если уж С++, то чем стандартный sort с компаратором не устроил?

Comment: Язык какой? 

И еще, Вам за один просмотр массива и на месте? Иначе используйте любую подходящую сортировку, при сравнении четного с нечетным считайте, что четный меньше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите индекс `i`, установите его в номер последнего элемента и уменьшайте до тех пор, пока элемент по этому индексу не станет чётным. (Если упрётесь в начало, алгоритм окончен.) Пройдитесь по массиву от начала к концу до индекса `i`. Если видите нечётный элемент, обменяйте его с элементом по индексу `i`, и уменьшайте `i` до тех пор, пока не найдёте чётный элемент. Всё.

Таким образом, достаточно одного просмотра, время работы `O(длина массива)`.

Comment: "время работы O(длина массива)" Впервые вижу такое обращение с нотацией O(n).

Comment: @Kromster: а что, вроде бы самоочевидно и правильно :)

Comment: Что-то не припомню, чтобы О нотация описывала временную сложность в простых числах.